How would I train a neural net on multiple different computers?
I have no experience with AI whatsoever, and I'm considering creating a relatively simple model just to actually get into AI creation. However, I have a relatively bad GPU (GT 1030) and I'm worried that I won't have enough power to train it. I also may be able to gain access to around 20 computers with Quadro series GPUs, which I don't remember the exact model of, but I know they had 2 GB VRAM. Would there be a way that I could train my model across all of them, despite them being separate computers? Or would my weak GPU be sufficient to train a relatively small model?

check Kubernetes.

Yes you could do it but it would be involved.
Assuming your model is in pytorch you could use Distributed Data Parallel.
All the computers must be nodes on the same network. Network should be fast, so preferably >1Gbps ethernet. A shared storage space would also be beneficial to reduce passing too many data between the nodes. You also need to set up password-less ssh connection between the nodes.
Then you need to fire up the DDP code for each computer with something like this:
#!/bin/bash

MASTER_ADDR="192.168.1.1"
MASTER_PORT=12355
WORLD_SIZE=20  # Total number of nodes
BASE_IP="192.168.1." 

# Loop to start nodes
# Assuming nodes have sequential IPs
for ( i=1; i<$WORLD_SIZE; i++ )
do
    NODE_IP="${BASE_IP}$i"
    ssh user@$NODE_IP "MASTER_ADDR=$MASTER_ADDR MASTER_PORT=$MASTER_PORT WORLD_SIZE=$WORLD_SIZE RANK=$i python inference.py" &

wait  # Wait for all nodes to finish

Another option which could be easier to use is "model partioning". This means that you can load a part of your model that fits on your GPU memory memory, run inference and, write the results to the disk. When one part finishes, offload it and load then next part. This is continued sequentially until the whole process is done.
